# Trying to edit some static text on a WordPress contact form

Tags: wordpress

I've inherited this site and I'm having trouble locating where to find the text content to edit for some text that appears on a contact form. On the right side you'll see a phone number and email address. This information does not appear when I edit the form and I don't know where I might go to edit it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can edit using Contact us page

First research about wordpress pages, post and then if you have query then post here. its very basic of wordpress

Also share your wordpress version name, theme name and editor plugin name - page edit have different layout in each theme & editor.

```
Pages -> All Pages -> Edit (Contact Page)
```